# Azure Bot: There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Forbidden

Tags: node.js, azure, http, botframework

PROBLEM: When I try to test my bot using the web chat in the MS Azure GUI, it gives me the error

```
There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Forbidden
```

I've done the following:

- Created a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework, LUIS, and NodeJS
- Created resource for the bot in MS azure
- Successfully tested the bot locally using the bot emulator (without using the bot ID and password)
- Set up continuous deployment so all updates made to my repo are reflected in the Azure bot service
- Defined all environment variables in the application settings tab of the azure bot service (bot id and password are correct and included)
- Included web.config, iisnode.yml, and publish.js files

Heeelp. I've googled this, tried alternative solutions mentioned for similar problems, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

NEVERMIND! I had stopped the application weeks ago, that's why it gave the forbidden error. I didn't realize until I tried to make a GET request in Postman to the bot endpoint.